# What is the airlock on Rassvet meant for?

Tags: iss, rassvet, pirs

When NASA launched [Rassvet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rassvet_%28ISS_module%29) (DCM - Docking and Cargo Module) on a shuttle, it carried a small airlock attached.  NASA was under contract to deliver 1.4 tonnes of equipment for the [MLM Nauka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauka_%28ISS_module%29).

[Nauka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauka_%28ISS_module%29), which is the replacement for Pirs, and is really FGB-2 rebuilt for this purpose will have a docking node with an airlock module attached.

I was wondering if the airlock launched on Rassvet is meant for the port on Nauka.  (Which is due for launch in March-April 2014, if all goes well).  Or is it actually in use on Rassvet these days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And in updating the question, I found my answer.  Yes.

The Wikipedia page on [Nauka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauka_%28ISS_module%29) says:

> Outfitting equipment launched in 2010 with the Rassvet (Mini-Research Module 1) on NASA's STS-132 will also be used for Nauka, including the spare elbow joint for the European Robotic Arm, internal hardware and an experimental airlock to be positioned on one of the side-facing ports at the bottom of the module.

So the arm joint, the airlock and some extra stuff in Rassvet is meant for Nauka.

I have been reading [Anatoly Zak's Russian Space book](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/book_future.html), which is great, and this detail is not made clear.  At one point it looks like the airlock module would launch on its own Progress based module.

Comment: There is also a radiator (folded) attached that is meant for Nauka. The ERA on Nauka will detach these and transfer them to Nauka. The spare ERA part will remain on MRM-1.